# Constructing binary variable based on optimal fit

Tags: r, machine-learning, logistic, multiple-regression, stata

I have a dataset containing a continuous variable (A) which incompletely reflects a binary latent variable (L), but is close to the truth. I also have information on a few other, binary, variables (B/C/D/E/..) that also incompletely reflect the latent binary variable.

I would like to train combinations of B/C/D/E on variable A to create one new binary variable to represent L. Would this be possible? How could I do this, for example in R or stata?

Could this be done using a regression and predict a binary response?  I am a bit confused because my outcome is continuous, and would like to explain it with binary variables to predict another binary variable (A~B+C+D+E ). what other learning method could I use?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use a [finite mixture model](http://repec.org/snasug08/deb_fmm_slides.pdf) to do something like this. In Stata, try something like this:

```
sysuse auto, clear
ssc install fmm 
ssc install fmmlc
fmm price foreign mpg, comp(2) mixtureof(lognormal)
fmmlc, savec savep
```

This gives you the most likely latent class membership and the latent class posterior probabilities as 3 variables. You will probably need to change the lognormal to something more suitable for your data.

Other ideas are sem/gsem or gllamm. There are good Stata Press books for both.